# how to get maximum memory usage of a process compiled by gcc-mingw

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I have a C++ code. I can edit it. I want to get the maximum memory usage of the process which is made by the code, so I am finding some functions to peek the memory usage.

I've been searching this for three days, but I can't find any information. (I tried some of them, such as `GetProcessMemoryInfo`, but it didn't work)

Please give me some advice. Thanks :)

Comment: I think you posted it earlier. Can you elaborate on how `GetProcessMemoryInfo` didn't work? There is not much to expect unless you do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried some of them, such as `GetProcessMemoryInfo`, but it didn't work

The following, based on [Collecting Memory Usage Information For a Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), works for me:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                           PROCESS_VM_READ,
                           FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId() );
    if (NULL != hProcess) {
        if ( GetProcessMemoryInfo( hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc)) ) {
            printf( "PeakWorkingSetSize: 0x%08X\n", pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize );
            printf( "WorkingSetSize: 0x%08X\n", pmc.WorkingSetSize );
            // ... add other members from pmc, as needed ...
        }
        CloseHandle( hProcess );
    }
}
```

Compile and link with `g++ -o procinfo procinfo.cpp -lpsapi`.